# Cordova app crash after splash screen in iOS 12 with MobileIron

Tags: ios, mdm, mobileiron

After OS 12 upgrade one of our app start crashing, it was working fine till iOS 11. This issue has been observed with app distributed using MobileIron.

Some of the logs here might show the problem

```
Default 11:55:27.515281 -0700
SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x101df3300; Compass (com.mycompany.myApp); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x280136c10; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)> {
    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x280fa82a0; pid: 454; taskState: Running; visibility: Foreground>;
    terminationRequest = <FBSProcessTerminationRequest: 0x2814526c0; label: "watchdog provision violated"; exceptionCode: "Watchdog Violation (0x8BADF00D)"; reportType: CrashLog; explanation: "scene-create watchdog transgression: com.mycompany.myApp exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.80 seconds">;
    watchdogContext = <FBProcessWatchdogEventContext: 0x2801bcde0; event: scene-create> {
        updateContext = <FBSceneUpdateContext: 0x2816ebf80; scene: com.mycompany.myApp; tID: 1> {
            settings = <UIApplicationSceneSettings: 0x28256fcd0> {
                displayConfiguration = <FBSDisplayConfiguration: 0x2835fc270; Main; mode: "375x667@2x 60Hz sRGB SDR"> {
                    CADisplay.name
default 11:55:27.515653 -0700
SpringBoard lock/volume priority is:volume
```

I am stuck here. 
Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Manish Kumar

Comment: The log says that your app hung on launch; after 20 seconds it still hadn't started, so the watchdog process killed it. It is unlikely to be Mobileairon directly; it just distributes the ipa file.  You need to investigate more and provide code before we can help

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the quick response. This app works fine when distributing with appstoreconnect.